# linq join with case condition

Tags: linq

Hi may i know how to do a select "case" condition in using linq?
The commented out code are my question. how do i put the condition there?
my code:

```
var r = from u in Users
    join p in Payments on u.Id equals p.UserId
    join soi in SaleOrderItems on p.ReferenceId equals soi.Id
           //if soi.InventoryTypeId == 1
              //then join i in Inventories on soi.InventoryOrCourseId equals i.Id
           //elseif soi.InventorytypeId ==2
              //then join c in Courses on soi.InventoryOrCourseId equals c.Id
    where u.Id == 5
    select new{ u, p, soi, either i or c};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use some outer join trick to accomplish this, one straightforward method is via `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Essentially you create an inner join then expand it with missing rows:

```
var r = from u in Users
    join p in Payments on u.Id equals p.UserId
    join soi in SaleOrderItems on p.ReferenceId equals soi.Id
    join i in Inventories on new {a = soi.InventoryTypeId, b = soi.InventoryOrCourseId } equals new {a = 1, b = i.Id} into g1
    from oi in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join c in Courses on new {a = soi.InventoryTypeId, b = soi.InventoryOrCourseId } equals new {a = 2, b = c.Id} into g2
    from oc in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where u.Id == 5
    select new{ u, p, soi, ic = oi ?? oc};
```

Be careful about this last statement `ic = oi ?? oc`, since the types differ the anonymous type will use System.Object declaration so it can accommodate both types, if you want to use strong typed support maybe a better option would be to return both oc and ic and then test. You should best decide that based on how you use this query late ron.

Comment: @mmix hi i got this error " The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'." at the line join i in Inventories on new {a...

Comment: What type is `soi.InventoryTypeId`? Since I imagine `type(soi.InventoryOrCourseId)` equals `type(Inventory.Id)` then it must be that `soi.InventoryTypeId` is not `int`. If so, decorate constants 1 and 2 with a proper type suffix (U, L, etc)

Comment: @mmix: yes both of them are exactly int

Comment: Its probably not `int` but nullable int, `int?`, its often missed. Try casting constants into (int?). That error is very concrete, it cannot be anything else but type mismatch.
I posted a code snippet online which does this query on an offline array set. http://codepad.org/PGhG9i2S

Comment: strange!! i had changed my code to this -   join i in db.Inventories on new { a = Convert.ToInt16(soi.InventoryTypeId), b = Convert.ToInt16(soi.InventoryOrCourseId) } equals new { a = (int)InventoryTypes.Product, b = i.Id } into g1   .. but it still giving me same error. I have double confirm that all my table SaleOrderItems ,Inventories have the id as int.

Comment: int is System.Int32, not Int16

Comment: ok, start removing converts now and use casting `(int)`. Not sure if Convert would play nicely with expression tree, you might get suboptimal query as a result.