# using case statement in a join with linq

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to convert this SQL query into a linq query but not having much luck.

```
SELECT DISTINCT     gen.ID
                ,   gen.Name
                ,   Ssec.System 
FROM                dbo.Generic Gen
JOIN                dbo.SystemsSelected SSel
ON                  Gen.RecordID = SSel.RecordID
JOIN                dbo.Security SSec
ON (
            SSel.SystemA = CASE WHEN Ssec.System = '1stSystem' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
        OR  SSel.SystemB = CASE WHEN Ssec.System = '2ndSystem' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
    )
and SSec.Username = 'myUserName'
```

I've had a look at the following posts but cannot apply the examples to my code:

[Link join with case condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953952/linq-join-with-case-condition)

[Linq query with table joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352373/linq-query-with-table-joins-case-statements-count-group-by-clauses)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: If you are using Entity Frameworks, you should avoid join/distinct or any SQL level queries, instead you should simply use navigation properties

Comment: @AkashKava I have to join because i'm defining system security and only those people who have access should view code.  I am using Entity Framework and not sure what you mean by 'navigation properties'.  I add my tables in the Model and then use c# to retrieve that i need

Comment: Queries with Navigation properties will automatically create necessary joins/distincts/groups etc, you dont do it by using Entity Framework. If you show the model, I can show you the query.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer my own question directly but I found a workaround.

I used linq to instead call a Stored Procedure and that worked fine.

To do this:

1) Save code as a Stored Procedure that accepts a parameter named UserName
2) add the SP into Entity Framework Model
3) call the SP using:

```
public JsonResult GetNewTeams(string userUserName)
    {
        using (YourDBNameEntities db = new YourDBNameEntities ())
        {

            var ret = db.SP_YourStoredProcedureName(userUserName).ToList();

            return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

Thats it, done, no more scary linq!! :)

sauce: [Using stored procedures in LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/using-stored-procedure-in-linq/)